# Android set background resource and color

Tags: android

Is it possible to set the `backgroundResource` and `backgroundColor` of a ListView/ExpandableListView in a custom adapter.

I have a transparent png that will serve as the border for each row in an expandable listview.   This image is just an inner shadow and a border on the bottom.

The goal is to do something like this:

[image: png + color]

When I set the backgroundResource and then backgroundColor, only one of the two shows up.  I can't get the resource to overlay the color.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Here is my code to get a better idea:

```
private int[] colors2= new int[] { Color.parseColor("#e2e8e9"), Color.parseColor("#f1f2f2") };
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    ExpandListGroup group = (ExpandListGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_group_item, null);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    int colorPos = groupPosition % colors.length; 
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_forground);
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(color2[colorPos]);
    holder.title.setText(group.getName());
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setBackgroundResource` and `setBackgroundColor` both use the same api `setBackgroundDrawable` internally to do their tasks. So one overwrites the other. So you wont be able to achieve your goal using this api.

You will have to use setBackgroundResource with a custom drawable

Comment: I'm really doing it to see the best combination for colors in my program.  What I have mocked up in Photoshop doesnt render the same on the device so I wanted to find an easy/quick way of changing the colors instead of having to remake .9.png files.  But I ended up using a layer-list then setting the drawable to that.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `setBackgroundResource` and `setBackgroundColor` you can do this:

```
...
int colorPos = groupPosition % colors.length;
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_forground);
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) convertView.getBackground();
drawable.setColor(color2[colorPos]);
...
```

Comment: I'm getting this exception java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Answer (score 1):

There is for sure code which can take background drawable and use paint some color on it. But I can't rember now :-)
But there is other ways how can you achieve your goal. Look at this site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html
Look at 9patch drawables which you can prepare, which will be only small images which will shrink/expand as needed. You prepare one with and other color inside.
The second way is to use ShapeDrawable. In XML you create rectangle and some solid color inside it.
In both cases you just swap background drawables as needed.
I don't understand what you want exactly achieve, but I hope that this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a ColorFilter after setting your background ressource to the view like this

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourRessource);
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(
                Color.yourColor,
                PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER
);
```

Learn more about [Manipulating images and Drawables with Android’s ColorFilter](https://medium.com/over-engineering/manipulating-images-and-drawables-with-androids-colorfilter-25bf061843e7)